# Memory limit for update to Pimcore v4

Tags: php, pimcore

I just tried to do an update from Pimcore version 3.1.1 to 4.0.0. After downloading the required files and installing to nearly 20% the update stops and i get blank pages, both in frontend and backend.
In debug.log I can see 2 errors, saying two database columns could not be created, because they already exist. But these errors are in the middle of the logfile and don't seem to be the issue.
The PHP memory limit on this server is set to 256M.

I wonder if the memory limit could cause this problems. As I don't have direct access to the server I'm not able to change the php.ini myself.

So my question is: Should I increase the memory limit? What would be a good value for updating Pimcore? Or are 256M enough and I have some other issues with the update?

Answer (score 0):

I have an instance with 512MB, used by rather complex queries.

Regarding your error: which PHP version are you running on? Versions 3 and 4 are running with PHP7 without Problems.